# Kendo Drop Down List not showing data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am trying to create a Kendo Dropdownlist and it will not call the read.Action for some reason.  I cannot figure out what I am missing.

I have set the read.Action to different methods and it works but it just will not call it to this specific method.  I have verified that I am spelling it correctly and I've set breakpoints on everything to find what it runs.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("productionline-dropdown")
            .DataTextField("Id")
            .DataValueField("Name")
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read => { read.Action("GetDropDownList", "Home"); });
            })
 )

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetDropDownList()
{
    var productionLines = _productionLineService.GetAll().Select(x => new ProductionLineViewModel
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        CreatedAt = x.CreatedAt,
        UPE = x.UPE,
        ComputerName = x.ComputerName,
        ActiveLine = x.ActiveLine
    });


    return Json(productionLines, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I want my DropDownList to populate with the Names of the ProductionLines not the Ids.  Thanks

Comment: Might be because the action is decorated with HttpPost

Comment: Weird that that was the reason.  Every other Kendo read uses HttpPost.

Comment: I don't think that's weird. The control has to make a decision which request to send to fetch the data, it cannot send both post and get and see which one returns. So in this case it sends get, which the code doesn't handle

Answer (score 0):

This is because the action is decorated with `HttpPost`, while the control apparently sends Get (quite logically) to fetch the data. Remove this attribute, and that should fix it.